# what does "ClassCastException java.lang.Character cannot be cast to clojure.lang.Named" mean?

Tags: clojure, cascalog

In a toy cascalog based project, I'm trying to use cascalog.more-taps because it contains some facilities to read and write to/from the filesystem.

When loading my namespace I get this error message

```
user=> (use 'playground.adult-dataset)

ClassCastException java.lang.Character cannot be cast to clojure.lang.Named clojure.core/name (core.clj:1489)
user=>
```

I see it's deep into clojure core, so before digging into it I was wondering if anyone knows anything about this.

2 quick notes:

cascalog.more-taps requires clojure 1.3.0 OR 1.4.0 while cascalog supports up to clojure 1.5.1

The same error message showed up with Matchure, which is quite old and appears to be not maintained anymore.

Comment: This is likely an error in your name space declaration.  Can you post that?

Comment: @sw1nn
(ns playground.adult-dataset
  (:use
        [clojure.tools.namespace.repl :only (refresh)]
        [playground.mockdata]
        [cascalog-more-taps "0.3.0" :only (lfs-delimited)]
     ;; [cascalog.checkpoint]))

Comment: Remove the "0.3.0" and you should be fine. Just make sure the respective dependencies are contained in your project.clj.

Comment: @xsc thanks. I just got confused and pasted lines intended for the project file in the :use form in the namespace declaration. Once fixed that and "lein clean"ed, it went smooth. Sorry for the fuss.